# How to mouse right click event to dynamic create datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I create DataGridView into TableLayoutPanel.
so, how to right click event for each datagridview??
Here is the Dynamic datagridview create source code

```
public void makeDataGridView(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            DataGridView[] dgv = new DataGridView[num];

            dgv[i] = new DataGridView();
            dgv[i].Name = "dgv" + i.ToString();
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(dgv[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public void makeDataGridView(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        DataGridView[] dgv = new DataGridView[num];

        dgv[i] = new DataGridView();
        dgv[i].Name = "dgv" + i.ToString();
        dgv[i].MouseDown += onMouseDown;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(dgv[i]);
    }
}
private void onMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
       //perform task ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `MouseUp` event instead of `MouseDown`. `MouseDown` will fire instantly when you press button but `MouseUp` will fire after unpressed just like the behavior of Context Menu.